# Check variable is the plural of an array value

Tags: php, arrays

I want to run an in_array and return true if the variable is a plural version of an array value. I don't want to add the plurals of each word to the array.

```
$username = 'admins';

$blacklist = [
    'admin',
    'administrator',
    'mod',
    'moderator',
    'staff',
    'team',
    'owner',
];

if(in_array($username, $blacklist))
    echo 'yep';
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
foreach($blacklist as $item){
  if(strpos($item,$username)!== false){
    echo 'found';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check of username ends with s, remove s and match against array

```
if (strrpos($username, 's') === strlen($username)-1 && in_array(substr($username, 0, -1), $blacklist)) {
    echo 'yes';
}
```